# sitemap in Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

I am using Dotnetnuke( version 6). I want to add sitemap(which only shows the hyperlinks of pages) on my website. I have gone through number of free sitemap modules on the internet Like

1. http://www.derektrauger.com/Products/DotNetNukeModules/DNNSiteMapModule.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12645/DotNetNuke-SiteMap

all of them works fine and shows the link on first level but they does not show the page link of hidden pages and pages within pages. I have given full permission and sitemap link(steMap.aspx) also show hidden page.

how can i resolve this issue? 
Is there any other free sitemap module which can resolve this issue?

Regards and Thnakx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come you are not using the core sitemap?

e.g. www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.aspx

It should print out all pages in your site.

Mine currently prints out all pages http://www.ventrian.com/sitemap.aspx, even ones that hidden by "show in menu" set to false http://www.ventrian.com/Home/WhereAreThey.aspx

--

Just to update this thread, I actually use this for sitemaps now:
http://searchenginesitemaps.codeplex.com/

It is an open source sitemap for DotNetNuke. http://www.ventrian.com/SearchEngineSitemap.aspx

It allows for module developers to write their own providers to include their specific date in the sitemap (e.g. galleries, articles, etc).

Comment: Actually the core site map does not shows the pages in a tree format. I want a module (sitemap), which show the all pages url in a tree like structure.

Comment: Ah, I see, I got confused with a Google sitemap. You first link you posted, you will need to remove this out of line 61 of SiteMap.cs: (objTab.IsVisible) and recompile.